# Multiple wget calls in a single session?

Tags: linux, command-line, wget

I have the following code to retrieve a page from a website that needs authentication (it uses Sungard Higher Education authentication):

```
wget --delete-after --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --post-data 'user=foo&password=bar&uuid=0x123' login.php
wget --load-cookies cookies.txt thepage.com
```

But the problem is that the second one doesn't work. When I run the first one, it says I was successfully logged in but I get login required on the second.

I tried matching the POST/GET calls to be exactly like that on the browser by adding `--header` for each header I got from the HTTP call extracted from Chrome's developer tools, but it still didn't work.

I think the problem is that the authentication isn't cookies-based, and I'm opening a new session with each wget call. How would I prevent that from happening (if that's what happening)?

I think what I want to do is send the HTTP request and basically "navigate" to the page, which I'd imagine is one wget call, but I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to not use `--keep-session-cookies`? Banner might be generating a new user session with each `wget` which likely would cause the credentials you're providing to not be accepted.

Comment: @Bratchley I'm using it (see above) and how do I go about that?

Comment: You're using it in your first command which you're saying does work for you but the second one, the one you say isn't working, is missing that option.

Comment: @Bratchley I tried using that as well, not working. By the way, I feel like cookies.txt is missing cookies. Although I don't think it's the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `--input-file` switch and feeding it a text file containing your URL(s) should allow you to use only one wget invocation/session with all the other switches you need.